# Trouble defining controller for the ItemViewClass of a CollectionView.

Tags: ember.js

I am having trouble defining the controller for the ItemViewClass of a CollectionView.

I have a ArrayController with a defined ItemController and a CollectionView with a defined ItemView.

The CollectionView renders each Item with the correct ItemView, but fails to assign the ItemController as the controller.

Here is an example:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> 
    [
      Ember.Object.create({name: 'row 1'})
      Ember.Object.create({name: 'row 2'})
      Ember.Object.create({name: 'row 3'})
    ]

App.IndexRowController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  actions:
    test: -> alert "Item Controller"

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  itemController: 'indexRow'
  actions:
    test: -> alert "Array Controller"

App.IndexView = Ember.CollectionView.extend
  contentBinding: 'controller'
  itemViewClass: Em.View.extend
    templateName: 'row'

### Templates
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="row">
  <button {{action 'test'}}>
    {{view.content.name}}
  </button>
</script>
```

It seems to me this should just work? Anyone have any ideas?

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iDISOCi/1/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was pretty simple. Just had to bind the controller property of the itemViewClass to the content property.

```
App.IndexView = Ember.CollectionView.extend
  contentBinding: 'controller'
  itemViewClass: Em.View.extend
    controllerBinding: 'content'
    templateName: 'row'
```

Comment: But this sets the controller to the item content, not to the item controller.

Comment: Yes because the item content is a ObjectController. I think the collection view needs some work, It should auto detect if the content is an array of object controllers and assign them properly. Here is a working example http://jsbin.com/iDISOCi/2